# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I tried to `setState` inside `setInterval` function and I got:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

Any help?

```
useEffect(() => {
  NewTimer()
}, [])

const NewTimer = () => {
  let count = 0
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    count++
    if (count === 10) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    setCounter(count)
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: add here your component full source to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because your interval is running though your component has unmounted (I don't know if it has, but it might). I suggest that you do like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let count = 0
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    count++
    if (count === 10) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    setCounter(count)
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, [])
```

The returned function in the `useEffect` callback is called when your component unmounts. The code just clears the interval when the component is unmounted.

Comment: @AlexisZerdis Please accept my answer then, so future readers can see what worked