# React: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I have a component that throw the following error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Linear (at Linear.jsx:17)
```

And this is the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

const Linear = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((oldProgress) => {
        if (oldProgress === 100) {
          return 0;
        }
        const diff = Math.random() * 10;
        return Math.min(oldProgress + diff, 100);
      });
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setProgress(null);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Linear;
```

Line 17 is = 'setProgress((oldProgress) => {'.

I already tried [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513066/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component-with-setinterval) without any success to solve it.

What am I missing?

Comment: It might be that `setProgress(null)` that is called from the function returned by `useEffect`. This function runs after the component is “unmounted”.

Comment: @tromgy no change after I comment this.